# Fast Filtering a dropdown with more than 10000 items

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox

I have more than 10000 items listed in a Select Tag (Drop Down).

I have used [**Select2.js**](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) and **[jquery.sexycombo.js](https://code.google.com/p/sexy-combo/)** so far but both lack with the speed of rendering HTML and further filtering data.

Basically i am making a combobox with Autocomplete and AutoFill features say for e.g if we type "A" in combobox only items starting with "A" get filtered.

Below is the image for Select 2:
[image]

Below is the image for sexy combo:
[image]

I just want more idea about how to make my dropdown filter more than 10000 items faster as possible.
I have large data but i dont have idea how can i filter it faster as above combbox make them slow with large data.

Comment: Congratulations! Did you want to ask a question as well ?

Comment: Sorry ,Yeah @adeneo i want good idea to make my combobox work faster

Comment: You can't, you should reduce the datasets instead.

Comment: Even in 5000 items it gets slow & large data is the necessity , isn't their any possibility? @adeneo ?